# Plots without the 'plot()' function

Tags: matlab, plot

I am trying to learn how the graphic objects work in MATLAB. I tried to create a plot without using the plot function but I am confused why it is not working.

AFIK, when I use the plot function it creates figure, axis, line objects and then sets the property of each object accordingly. I tried to do so but all I'm getting is a white/blank figure.

I'm trying to plot a sine wave so my X and Y data are:

```
x = 0:0.1:2*pi;
y = sin(x);
```

This is my main code:

```
figH = figure();
axis([-2, 2, -2, 2]);
lineH = findobj(figH, 'type', 'line');
set(lineH, 'XData', x,...
           'YData', y,...
           'Color', 'r');
```

The weird thing is that when I type

```
get(lineH)
```

I'm not getting anything back. I appreciate tips and comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create the `line` before you can find it and change a property.
e.g.

```
hLine = line ( x, y, .... );
% Then you can modify the properties, i.e.
set ( hLine, 'XData', x );  
% etc...
```

**Edit:**

Its a good idea to create and store each of your objects directly (rather than allowing the command to find the appropriate figure, axes etc....)

```
hFig = figure;
hAx = axes ( 'parent', hFig );
hLine = line ( hAx, x, y, .... );
```

Comment: I see. That's why `get(lineH)` is not returning anything. I thought creating a figure would create a line if it is not already created. Why `findobj(figH, 'type', 'line')` doesn't return an error when there is no line yet?

Comment: Its not an error because it doesn't find any - it simply returns an empty array.  Consider that you can have many lines on a figure (on many different axes) so there is no way for that object to be created when you create a figure.

Comment: Hm, makes sense. So I have to create a line object first before setting its properties, using `line()`.

Comment: I don't have to create the figure object because `line()` would create the figure it needs in order to survive.

Comment: true - but not best practice - as it may end up finding the wrong figure - see edit to answer.